# Finding Oracle stored procedures

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Since I am new to Oracle, please tell me what different ways to find packages, stored procedures, triggers, functions, indexes, tablespaces

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "find"?

Answer (score 1):

The following statement gives you an overview of all database objects in the current user:

```
SELECT
object_name,
object_type
        FROM
user_objects;
```

If you are searching for documentation, you can look at [Morgan's Library](http://www.psoug.org/reference/library.html)

Comment: There are also a variety of other data dictionary views that may be useful, eg. `USER_PROCEDURES`, `USER_TRIGGERS`, `USER_INDEXES`

Answer (score 1):

You can download [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html) free.  This allows you to explore all the objects in your database via a simple interface.

Answer (score 0):

I shall walk you through the different shades of "all_object":

```
SQL> show user
USER is "C##SCOTT"
SQL>
```

Getting all the types of object:

```
select distinct object_type from all_objects;

EDITION
CONSUMER GROUP
SEQUENCE
SCHEDULE
PROCEDURE
OPERATOR
DESTINATION
WINDOW
SCHEDULER GROUP
PACKAGE
PROGRAM
LOB
XML SCHEMA
JAVA RESOURCE
JOB CLASS
DIRECTORY
TABLE
SYNONYM
INDEX
VIEW
FUNCTION
INDEXTYPE
JAVA CLASS
TYPE
EVALUATION CONTEXT

25 rows selected.
```

Now, you can zoom down to the "TABLE" type of object:

```
select object_name||','||object_id||','||owner from all_objects where object_type='TABLE' ;
```

Or all the objects of an owner:

```
select object_name||','||object_id||','||OBJECT_TYPE from all_objects where owner = 'SYS';
```

Trust me, you will learn more this way - anyone can click through any GUI tool, but to issue the SQL command, you will need some knowledge.